# Cannot access this.params variable in data: property in iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

The following code does not work when the url is /company/martin:

```
 this.route('scheduledTasks', {
    path: '/company/:name',
    data: {
      items:
      function(){
        return scheduledTasks.find({company: this.params.name});
      }
    }
```

While this does work:

```
 this.route('scheduledTasks', {
    path: '/company/:name',
    data: {
      items:
      function(){
        return scheduledTasks.find({company: "martin"});
      }
  }
```

I tried several solutions, but it seems that **this.params.name** does not exist or cannot be accessed??

Comment: Try console logging `this` and see what it is.

Comment: I get items and yield as properties, but no params...

Comment: So `this` isn't what you think it is, as the function creates a new scope, and `this` no longer references the route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.params.name` needs to be evaluated within the context of the route, and I believe that only can happen if `data` is a function and not an object literal. Try this:

```
this.route('scheduledTasks', {
  path: '/company/:name',
  data: function() {
    var company = this.params.name;
    return {
      items: function() {
        return scheduledTasks.find({company: company});
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: That's it! Can you give some further explanation why I need to use a function? Or maybe a resource that makes me better understand this behaviour?

Comment: The value of `this` changes depending on how a function is evaluated. According to the [ir docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#data), if `data` is a function it is evaluated when the route is run so you have have access to `params`. If data is an object literal, it will be evaluated later on by the template (`this` will be a template instance) and will therefore not have access to `params`. In the solution above, we avoid this problem by binding the `name` value to a variable which will be available to the `find` whenever it is called.

Comment: Yup makes sense once explained, but one of those things I'd never had worked out on my own. Thanks!